# If a unicode character displays in a web safe font, is it safe to use?

Tags: html, unicode, html-entities

Sorry if this is a dumb question but searching around has hurt my brain so I'd like someone to clear this up.

Say I want to use a unicode character (e.g. one of the arrows). I'm using a font that is web safe so will be on 99% of computers (for example Arial, Georgia, etc.). I copy and paste the symbol into my editor, press save and preview on the browser and it shows. Is that it? Will this be safe as long as everyone has the same font?

Should I paste the character entity instead to make sure that it doesn't mess with code?

Comment: Note that the browser may already substitute a font you have (but others may not) for that single character. Just because you specify a certain font doesn't mean it gets used for all glyphs. You would want to make sure that the font really contains that character and not just that it displays fine in your browser (which basically tells nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, if it's safe to say that 99% of your visitors have a font that can display that character, it's fine.

Using an entity would not make it safer. It would just mean you don't have to think about encodings, which is bad. You should have to think about what encoding you are declaring your website to be in and what it's actually in and that both are correct.

An arrow like "→" is exactly the same as a character like "a", "ä", "あ", "Д" or any other character. You wouldn't want all those as entities, since that's a pain to work with, so you should rather make sure your toolchain handles encodings correctly so you can use them as is.

Comment: Thanks I thought that might be the case.